Problem mounting my volumes
I haven't used Ubuntu for a few years. In the last few weeks I decided to test the current version (24.04.1) on my new computer, booting from my USB stick (without installation).
When I used to use Ubuntu, I already used the NTFS system and I never had any problems, with the volumes mounted automatically, allowing me to read and write.
On my new computer I have two SSDs NVMe, both NTFS system, but I'm not able to mount them with the Ubuntu LiveUSB. I found several topics here and in other forums about the problem, but without success in my case. So I'm asking here again.
When I click on the icons of my volumes, the following message appears:
Unable to access "494 MB Volume"
Error mounting /dev/loop1 at /media/ubuntu/
disk: /dev/loop1 already mounted or mount point busy
The same message appears when I try to access the other volume, but replacing loop1 with loop2.
How can I solve the problem?
Thanks!
